# How i get the Number of Hour Minute and Second

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, time

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8HYl.png)
I Have Data and Query like this.

I want to get the result Number of hour, minute and seconds form max_time at End_Time - min_Time at Start_Time. Like 01:16:45 in Time.

Please help me if you know

Comment: To avoid downvotes and help your peers help you, add the query as formatted code to your question instead in an image link.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options for you here.

First, DATEPART:-

```
SELECT DATEPART(hour, getdate())
SELECT DATEPART(minute, getdate())
SELECT DATEPART(second, getdate())
```

Next, cast the Datetime to a Time

```
SELECT CAST(getdate() AS Time)
```